# Cocoapods generate bad xcconfig file - no header search path

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, header, cocoapods

I'm facing with a problem, that all of the libraries are not found in the project, and I figured out that the Pods.debug.xcconfig file does not contains a header search path so probably that's the reason of this, but I don't know why and how can I solve this problem.
My podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do

   pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.2'
   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.2'
   pod 'JSONHelper', '~> 1.6'

end
```

and the xcconfig file is this:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/Bolts.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/JSONHelper.framework/Headers"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -framework "Bolts" -framework "FBSDKCoreKit" -framework "FBSDKLoginKit" -framework "JSONHelper"
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) "-D" "COCOAPODS"
PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/Pods-Project
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and swift.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that to problem caused by this line: use_frameworks!
because I wanted to include JSONHelper which is written in swift.

Removing this and added the JSONHelper by hand solved the problem.